# d3.json() invoking callback multiple times for a single response

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery, d3.js

I created a couple generic-ish functions wrapping the d3.json() AJAX function.

```
this.getData4 = function(url, returnFunc, param1, param2, param3) {
  d3.json(url, function(returnData) {
    if (returnData !== null) {
      returnFunc(returnData, param1, param2, param3);
    }
  });
}
```

Yes, this is ugly.  Bear with me.  Inserting breakpoints on the second and third lines of this snippet will show me that my requests are sent properly.  For example, I send 4 requests, where `param1` = 0, 1, 2, and 3.  Then the responses come back into the anonymous callback function, and most will be duplicated - for example, I might get back a series of responses where `param1` = 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3.

Looking at my server log, there are only 4 requests hitting.  Looking at the network tab in Chrome, I'm seeing the correct number of responses.  But the callback function gets called multiple times from inside d3.

A bit more info: I'm using d3 2.4.2.  I also replaced the jQuery version inside d3/lib - the jQuery that shipped with d3 was 1.4.2, which seems to be the case even for the latest d3.  This jQuery has a serious memory leak in its AJAX methods, however, and to fix this I dropped in jQuery 1.7.2.  D3 never complained about the replacement, but as I can find no other info out there about this issue, I suspect there may not be strict compatibility between the two jQueries.

Comment: Try this in a console to check the version number: `d3.version`.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Edited the question to add that the D3 version is 2.4.2.  I'm not sure why my d3 files don't have v2 in the name like those in the git repo.

Comment: That's because the d3.v2.js change was made after v2.7.5. :)

Comment: By the way, D3 doesn't require jQuery and doesn't use it for AJAX. This sounds more like a quirk in your code. Perhaps a reproducible code sample would help get an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'll see if I can come up with something for this soon.